# How to connect to cloudantdb through node-red

Tags: cloudant, node-red

I am not able to connect to the cloudant service using the node-red installed on my laptop. It is showning the following error after entering the server as "morack.cloudant.com" which is my account on cloudant.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Authentication problem. Perhaps this library may help? -- http://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-cf-cloudant